# VirtualHost configuration not working

Tags: osx, apache-httpd, hosts

I followed [this article](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/set-virtual-hosts-apache-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/), mixed with some [other](http://mark-kirby.co.uk/2008/setting-up-virtual-hosts-on-os-x-leopard/) [research](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts), in an effort to get `VirtualHost` configuration up and running on my Mac. However, for some reason when I navigate to my `local.site.rocks` URL it ends up sending me to a search via my ISP (weird).

Here is my `httpd-vshosts.conf` file:

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
    ServerName site.rocks
    ServerAlias local.site.rocks
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/site.rocks-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/site.rocks-access_log" common
    <Directory "/var/www/site.rocks/public_html/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my `hosts` file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       local.site.rocks
```

I also made sure to uncomment the `Include` for the `vshosts` file. Furthermore, I did issue an `apachectl restart` before trying to navigate to the URL.

What did I miss here? It's got to be something simple.

Comment: Does `ping local.site.rocks` succeed or fail?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick it does succeed with a response from `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Maybe try the accepted answer to [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121425/how-can-i-get-osx-mavericks-to-notice-a-dns-change-in-etc-hosts)

Comment: @Omnipresence so that didn't fix it, but I did notice something; the search to my ISP is for `www.local.site.com`.

Comment: Maybe your browser is making an assumption about the URL. Is the behaviour any different if you browse to `http://local.site.rocks`? What if you change your `/etc/hosts` line to `127.0.0.1       local.site.rocks www.local.site.rocks` and add `www.local.site.rocks` as a `ServerAlias` in your `vhosts.conf`?

Comment: @Omnipresence that is the behavior with or without the protocol prefix. But, that might work; I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Omnipresence okay so that didn't work. This is so weird. It's got to be easier than this to setup local DNS that just directs traffic to a folder on disk.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using a Proxy in your browser?

Comment: @Omnipresence nope.

Comment: I feel like this must be your browser, but I can't be sure. What happens if you run `wget http://local.site.rocks` from a command line? Do you get back the expected page (albeit in plain text HTML)?